# PHP: __autoload function doesn't ever called

Tags: php, xampp, autoload

So, I have xampp. I tested this code on ZendServer, result the same.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

define ("ABS_PATH", 'C:\xampp\htdocs\oopHotLine\\');

function __autoload($class_name) {
    echo 'gg';
    require_once (ABS_PATH.'classes\\'.$class_name.'.php');
}

$process=new Main('1');
?>
```

after php.exe -a index.php i have this:

```
Interactive mode enabled
Fatal error: Class 'Main' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\oopHotLine\index.php on line 10
[Finished]
```

so, it doesn shows 'gg' output. If i manually do __autoload('Main'); - all OK. The same for the manual require_once or include. All permissions in windows folder set to full access. Php version - PHP Version => 5.3.8;

Please, help.

Comment: Are your sure the file is called?

Comment: When you load a custom function like the following with spl_autoload_register, does it work then?

Comment: Yes, i am quite sure, and, even if not - shouldn't it show 'gg' at first, before the error?

Comment: custom loader with spl_autoload_register have the same output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As DaveRandom pointed:

```
Autoloading is not available if using PHP in CLI interactive mode.
```

So, instead of using `php.exe -a index.php`, cut the `-a` off and try running the script with **`php.exe index.php`** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Notes from the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/__autoload) on this subject, that may be relevant:

Judging by the first message logged, this is probably the answer:

> Autoloading is not available if using PHP in CLI interactive mode.

...but also:

> spl_autoload_register() provides a more flexible alternative for autoloading classes. For this reason, using __autoload() is discouraged and may be deprecated or removed in the future.

Aside from this, here is how I would write your autoload function:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
  if (file_exists(ABS_PATH."classes/$class_name.php")) { // At least check the file exists before you require it!
    // Forward slashes work on Windows too (in PHP at least)... and they make it more portable
    require_once (ABS_PATH."classes/$class_name.php");
  }
}
```

Comment: `<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    define ("ABS_PATH", 'C:/xampp/htdocs/oopHotLine/');

    function autoload ($class_name) {
     echo 'gg';
        if (file_exists(ABS_PATH."classes/".$class_name.".php")) {
         require_once (ABS_PATH.'classes/'.$class_name.'.php');
     }
    }

    spl_autoload_register ('autoload');

    $process=new Main('1');
?>` gives the same output, sorry for formatting.

Comment: @NiPh I really think this is more to do with `Autoloading is not available if using PHP in CLI interactive mode.`...

Comment: Thank you for your help and information about future __autoload deprecation.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

> If your code has an existing __autoload function then this function
>   must be explicitly registered on the __autoload stack. This is because
>   spl_autoload_register() will effectively replace the engine cache for
>   the __autoload function by either spl_autoload() or
>   spl_autoload_call().